# Removing Nodes from XML - VBA

Tags: xml, vba, nodes

Whenever i create an XML on VBA using Access, it creates an xml file that is not readeable on the system i am using..

This is my XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataroot xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata" generated="2014-07-   22T15:53:26">
<Customers>
<Idx>1</Idx>
<FirstName>David</FirstName>
<LastName>McCollum</LastName>
<IconIdx>0</IconIdx>
<PhoneNumber>02870 354244</PhoneNumber>
<Email></Email>
<Street></Street>
<City></City>
<State></State>
<ZipCode></ZipCode>
<Available>1</Available>
<SPIndex>0</SPIndex>
```

So basically i create my table and then export it using a button command

```
Private Sub Export_Click()
Dim objOtherTbls As AdditionalData

Set objOtherTbls = Application.CreateAdditionalData

'Identify the tables or querys to export
objOtherTbls.Add "Customers"

'Here is where the export takes place
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
DataSource:="Customers", _
DataTarget:="C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\CustomersTest.xml", _
AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls

MsgBox "Export operation completed successfully."
End Sub
```

Basically i have three things which need to be done :)

1. The Root element needs to be changed to 'DatabaseData' instead of 'dataroot'
2. I need to remove the Child node *'xlmns:od'* before it is saved
3. I need t remove the child node *'generated'* before it saved?

the nodes are Child nodes of the 'dataroot'?

Any help would be much appreciated...

If this doesnt make sense i apologise.. its my first time of doing this :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the ExportXml function, make sure to give it the schematarget, then disregard that file.  Essentially, you're adding schema to the xml document by default, and since I don't see an option to turn that off in [Official Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193212(v=office.15).aspx), your best bet is to create then delete(kill) the .xsd afterwards if you don't need that additional info.

```
Application.ExportXML ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
DataSource:="Customers", _
DataTarget:="C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\CustomersTest.xml", _
SchemaTarget:="C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\DelMe.xsd", _
AdditionalData:=objOtherTbls

'may need a pause here  > do events loop to make sure it's finished
'DateTarget = DateAdd("s", 5, Now) '5 second pause here
'Do Until Now > DateTarget
'    DoEvents
'Loop    
Kill "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\DelMe.xsd"
```

We have determined it is hard to get it to exclude the tags you don't need, during the export.  A better solution, after the export, may be a a way to get just the customers nodes into its own separate XML file.

```
Call WriteNodesToNewFile("//Customers", "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\CustomersTest.xml", "C:\Users\David PC\Desktop\CustomersFINAL.xml")
```

Add this to the module,

```
Sub WriteNodesToNewFile(XPath As String, XmlFilePath As String, FinalXmlFilePath As String)
    'If you want intellisense on these Objects, go to Tools > Reference > Add Microsoft XML v6.0
    'This will output ONLY the collection of nodes you specify

    Set doc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    doc.validateOnParse = False
    doc.Load (XmlFilePath)
    Set GetNodes = doc.SelectNodes(XPath)

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FinalXmlFilePath, 2, True)

    For Each Item In GetNodes
        f.write Item.XML
    Next
    f.Close
    Set f = Nothing    

End Sub
```

Comment: No problem. The autogenerated stuff from some processes like this has been a pain for me before so you bend the XSD to fit your practical needs.

Comment: Ok... SO creating a schema is something that im trying to work on... but it is complicated and im not sure how to make it.. haha.. sorry.. when it searches for SchemaTarget on export is it effectively looking for a template of information?        also where/what is the best way to create a Schema to match my needs?

Comment: Ah, I just realized what is happening.  Give it the schematarget, then disregard that file.  Essentially, you're adding schema to the xml by default.

Comment: Which file shall i disregard?

Comment: Check out the updated code snippet.  I've revised my answer as I was looking at it from an Import perspective (which is what I'm typically using XML for)

Comment: I;ve tried to add this to my code, but its still not implementing properly?
Maybe i've got something wrong in the XDS?

ANy chance i could upload the XML/XSD and you have a look?

Or any way i can be of more help for you in trying to sort it?

Comment: What's it doing?  Is the xml above the most current iteration?

Comment: <DatabaseData>
<Customers>
 <Idx>0</Idx>
 <FirstName/>
 <LastName>Undefined</LastName>
 <IconIdx>0</IconIdx>
 <PhoneNumber/>
 <Email/>
 <Street/>
 <City/>
 <State/>
 <ZipCode/>
 <Available>1</Available>
 <SPIndex>0</SPIndex>
 </Customers>
 </DatabaseData>  This is the Format that i want the XML to save in, Where <Available>, <SPIndex> are unchangeable from 1 and 0  Does that make sense?

Comment: PS i apologise for all the comments.. i cant start a message?

Comment: No prob David, are the 1 and 0 fields saved as Yes/No in the database?

Comment: No every field is saved as Short Text.  Also i think the creating of a schema in XSD is going to be the hardest bit.. i have no idea what to do! haha

Comment: The schema creation was more for importing as I was looking at it wrong.  The only reason I had you change it to create the XSD is so that it doesn't include it with the xml, but it looks like you still have nodes to remove.

Comment: Yeh I still have nodes to remove when it's exported via vba.  I'm trying to work out if when it exports it effectively looks at a template of the exact info I want it to have ie all fields exported even if 'blank' and change the field name from dataroot to DatabaseDate